# Laravel ServiceProvider function to share with views

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a `ServiceProvider` in my `Laravel7` app, and I fetch data from the DB.

I need to access this data in my views, however I don't want to re-call the DB so I can minimize overhead.
Is this possible as I cant see any documentation on the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#service-providers) site.

Would be great if I could call something like..

`$this->app->set('mydata',$data);`

Comment: did you check the documentation for views?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Ahh thanks! exactly what I needed

Comment: @IEnumerable if you want to add an answer for the benefit of others who will come along that would be cool :)

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @lagbox and @apokryfos for their guidence, I was able to implement the following;

## ServiceProvider

In the boot method.

```
$modules = Module::where('is_installed', true)->get();

View::share( 'modules', $modules );
```

## View file

```
@foreach( $modules as $module)....
   ....
```